# Помогите пожалуйста с запросом SQL (Oracle). Having, Group by, агрегатная функция от агрегатной функции

Tags: sql, oracle, запрос, select, group-by

Задание - вывести фамилию-имя начальника отдела и название отдела, в котором сотрудники выполнили максимальное количество проектов.
У меня получился такой запрос, но выводит он не совсем то, что нужно.
Сделал его по примеру [отсюда](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_aggregate_function_to_aggregate_function/page3.html) (второй пункт).

```
SELECT department_name, max_amount FROM
(
    SELECT dep_name AS department_name, COUNT(rel_prj_id) AS projects_amount
    FROM employees
        INNER JOIN departments ON emp_dep_id = dep_id
        INNER JOIN rel_prj_emp ON rel_emp_id = emp_id
    GROUP BY dep_name
) X INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MAX(projects_amount) AS max_amount
    FROM
    (
        SELECT dep_name AS department_name, COUNT(rel_prj_id) AS projects_amount
        FROM employees
            INNER JOIN departments ON emp_dep_id = dep_id
            INNER JOIN rel_prj_emp ON rel_emp_id = emp_id
        GROUP BY dep_name
    ) X
) Y ON projects_amount = max_amount
```

Вывод, при том, что проекта всего три: [image: Результат запроса]

В чем проблема - я думаю, вы поймёте, если посмотрете на схему БД. Каждому отделу должно соответствовать несколько проектов, но отделы и проекты связаны через таблицу сотрудников - и поэтому в моём запросе каждому отделу соответствует больше записей, чем нужно.
Группирую по названию отдела, а получается, что в каждой группе - сотрудники этого отдела. Как связать таблицы иначе или сгруппировать иначе - я не придумал, в ступоре нахожусь. Если зайти с другой стороны, сгруппировать по id проекта - в каждой группе будет количество сотрудников, которое работало над проектом, тоже не то.
Нужно решение задачи именно по этой схеме. Я знаю, что можно упростить, но задание учебное.
Скрипт создания БД: http://pastebin.com/hnHnENpX.

[image: Схема БД]

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А у вас исходные данные для проверки некорректные. У вас в каждом отделе есть сотрудники которые работали над всеми проектами. count вы конечно не правильно берете, 10 - это количество сотруднико-проектов. `count(distinct rel_prj_id)` даст количество проектов по отделу. только с вашими данными во всех отделах по 3 проекта

Comment: @Mike, спасибо за ответ, count(distinct - вот в чём была проблема!    Да, я так и думал, что данные придётся изменить (просто выдали такие). Хотя вот сделал count(distinct - даже так показывает неправильно, без отдела администрации.

Comment: А разве должно показывать все отделы ? У вас задача получить отдел где максимальное кол-во проектов. такой отдел может быть и один. Или несколько, если в них одинаковое кол-во проектов

Comment: @Mike, ну, по идее в этом случае должен показывать все, т. к. над каждым проектом трудился каждый отдел. Ладно, другой вопрос - если вытаскивать имя-фамилию начальника отдела, тогда нужно ещё по 2 полям группировать? А результат запроса не изменится от этого?

Comment: С вашими данными, если distinct добавить в оба подзапроса то выводит все 3 отдела. Что бы получить начальника, надо еще раз приклеить в верхний запрос таблицу employees по полю id-начальника (там придется алиасы использовать у таблиц, что бы одинаковые по названию поля разрулить) и добавить в группировку имя именно из этой второй таблицы, тогда кол-во записей в группировке не изменится

Comment: @Mike, вот мне и показалось странным - выводит 3 отдела, а по идее 4 должно. Класс, пробую.

Comment: Почему 4 ? У вас в отделе кадров нет ни одного сотрудника, так что там и проектов не будет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT emp_first_name,emp_last_name,department_name, max_amount FROM
(
    SELECT dep_name AS department_name,e2.emp_first_name,e2.emp_last_name,
           COUNT(distinct rel_prj_id) AS projects_amount
      FROM employees e1
     INNER JOIN departments ON e1.emp_dep_id = dep_id
     INNER JOIN rel_prj_emp ON rel_emp_id = e1.emp_id
     INNER JOIN employees e2 ON e2.emp_id=dep_manager_id
     GROUP BY dep_name,e2.emp_first_name,e2.emp_last_name
) X INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MAX(projects_amount) AS max_amount
    FROM
    (
        SELECT dep_name AS department_name,
               COUNT(distinct rel_prj_id) AS projects_amount
          FROM employees
         INNER JOIN departments ON emp_dep_id = dep_id
         INNER JOIN rel_prj_emp ON rel_emp_id = emp_id
         GROUP BY dep_name
    ) X
) Y ON projects_amount = max_amount
```

Хотя верхний подзапрос немного странно смотрится, логичнее бы выглядело, если бы отделы были первой таблицей и к ней все клеилось. Хотя в данном случае порядок ни на что не влияет (т.к. в inner join таблицы слева и справа равнозначны).

Comment: (к комментарию) Да, точно, это я уже совсем затупил. / А зачем count(1) во втором запросе?

Comment: @Max Это я у себя разницу вывода смотрел этим подзапросом, просто осталось :) убрал из ответа

Comment: Отлично, спасибо огромное! Могу копеечку на пиво скинуть в качестве символической благодарности.